# An adjective for something being in question or under analysis

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Basically, what I'm after is an adjective with the same meaning as ***in question***.

For example:

> **(Adj) PV** was presented in brackets ...

as opposed to

> **the PV in question** was presented in brackets....

Thank you

Comment: Isn't "the PV in question" a noun, not an adjective?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the way it is, except it is a bit wordy. Why not "Also, in order to limit the range of the potential PVs that could be used to fill in the blanks by the participants, *an* equivalent *expression* was presented in brackets at the end of each sentence. Also,some might grumble at "each [...] were".

Comment: This doesn’t answer your question as posed, but you could consider the following re-write using the notion of “respective” at the end [and if it’s made clear elsewhere that all the correct answers will be phrasal verbs, you could consider just using “answer” instead of repeating “PV”]: “ … the closest equivalent to the meaning of each **correct/expected/appropriate** PV/{answer} was presented in brackets at the end of/{following} its **respective** sentence/{question}.”

Comment: Thanks Papa. It's close, but not quite what I have in mind.

Comment: How about "the PV being sought" ?

Comment: The word that comes to mind is "questionable".. the adjective that means, "in question." Pure and simple.

Comment: Alleged seems close, maybe putative.

Comment: Takes the rug from our feet rather when you remove the context rather than improving it. And  now nobody knows what PV stands for. What's wrong with writing it in full?

Answer (score 1):

I would use ***implied***

> hinted at or suggested; not directly expressed
>
> - An ***implied** term* that permitted the bank to refuse to provide information to the claimants was also required.
>   ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/implied))

So your example could be written in this way:

> the ***implied*** PV was presented in brackets...

I also thought of ***targeted*** (as we speak of [target language](https://www.google.com/search?q=target%20language%20meaning&safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk02zma6a2Huw-xjchY1-WODGgc8yFA%3A1625259224950&source=hp&ei=2HzfYIW2N_ad1fAP_JmIoA4&iflsig=AINFCbYAAAAAYN-K6IpQOHsprpHy93sQE8tylgB6Uq7Q&oq=target%20lang&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIKCAAQkQIQRhD5ATIFCAAQkQIyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCC4yAggAMgIIADoECCMQJzoECAAQQzoKCAAQsQMQgwEQQzoNCC4QsQMQxwEQowIQQzoKCAAQsQMQyQMQQzoFCAAQkgM6CAgAELEDEJECOgcIABCxAxBDOgoIABCHAhCxAxAUOggILhDHARCvAVDOCFjVNmCfQmgAcAB4AIAB_wGIAdAKkgEFNS41LjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=gws-wiz) or of [target vocabulary](https://esolonline.tki.org.nz/ESOL-Online/Planning-for-my-students-needs/Resources-for-planning/Teaching-and-learning-sequences/Focus-on-English/Target-vocabulary)) and ***[intended](https://www.google.com/search?q=intended%20meaning&safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk03M0pf49E5r7pWe6xocDdkfAy2lpg%3A1625258129799&ei=kXjfYKWeMOO68gLu7YPQAg&oq=inten&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIJCCMQJxBGEPkBMgcIABCxAxBDMgoIABCHAhCxAxAUMgcILhCxAxBDMgQIABBDMgQIABBDMggIABCxAxDJAzIFCAAQkgMyAggAMgUIABCxAzoHCCMQsAMQJzoHCAAQRxCwAzoECCMQJzoFCAAQkQI6CAgAELEDEIMBOgsILhCxAxDHARCjAjoICC4QsQMQgwE6BwgAEIcCEBRKBAhBGABQgYIDWOqJA2CUoQNoAXACeACAAagBiAGeBZIBAzIuNJgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQnAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz)*** which means *"planned or meant"*.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the original question is that nowhere was it stated specifically in the example that the examinee is being asked to provide one specific phrasal verb, so that there wasn’t actually one in question. The poster just deleted the example, so the question is even more obscure. However we are to assume that a specific phrasal verb (PV) has been mentioned and there is a need to refer back to it.

One could refer to it simply as:

“**the required** [phrasal verb]”

or

“**the aforementioned** [phrasal verb]”

or even

“**that** [phrasal verb]”

(And I am not going to provide dictionary references for the adjectives. On EL&U I should be able to assume a certain level of literacy.)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of "the PV in question", try "the given PV".

This syntax is often used on standardized tests, in questions involving an element of mathematical substitution - everything from basic algebra up to complex physics and computer programming questions.  For example where an equation is presented and the student is asked to solve the equation with "the given values", or to find a solution that meets "the given criteria".  These criteria can be specific (and provided), or they can refer to unknowns that the student is meant to consider or resolve.

[Here is a SAT practice test](https://collegereadiness.collegeboard.org/pdf/sat-practice-test-2-answers.pdf) that uses this syntax dozens of times.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.